# In Ansible, how to use a variable inside a variable definition that uses filters

Tags: regex, jinja2, ansible

I want to extract a few regex matches out of a URL. The only way I could do this was following:

```
  - name: Set regex pattern for github URL
    set_fact: pattern="^(git\@github\.com\:|https?\:\/\/github.com\/)(.*)\/([^\.]+)(\.git)?$"

  - name: Extract organization name
    set_fact: project_repo="{{ deploy_fork | regex_replace( "^(git\@github\.com\:|https?\:\/\/github.com\/)(.*)\/([^\.]+)(\.git)?$", "\\3" ) }}"
    when: deploy_fork | match( "{{ pattern }}" )
```

With this approach, I'm able to reuse the variable `pattern` in the `match` filter, but not on the `set_fact` line where I assign the extracted text to another variable.
Is there any way to reuse the variable in `set_fact` that uses `filter(s)` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should just be able to reference the defined variables directly.  Try this; it worked for me:

```
- name: Set regex pattern for github URL
  set_fact: pattern="^(git\@github\.com\:|https?\:\/\/github.com\/)(.*)\/([^\.]+)(\.git)?$"
- name: Extract organization name
  set_fact: project_repo="{{ deploy_fork | regex_replace(pattern, "\\3" ) }}"
  when: deploy_fork | match(pattern)
```

Comment: What ansible version was this tested? I get: `No filter named ''match''`.

Answer (score 0):

> You don’t need to use {{ }} to use variables inside conditionals, as
>   these are already implied.

You can find detailed descriptions here [Ansible Conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement)