# Ansible regex_replace does not recognize the variable

Tags: regex, mongodb, ansible

I am trying to replace a string using regex_replace but I am having an issue with parameters.

```
vars:
    **mongoURI**: "mongodb://shard1:27017,shard2:27017,shard3:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0"

- name: Create Mongo connection string    
      set_fact:        
        **readinput**: "mongodb://{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).username }}:{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).password }}@" 
        readconnstring: "{{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', '{{ readinput }}') | regex_replace('\\?ssl', 'test?ssl') + ('&retryWrites=true') }}"
```

The above works fine and I get the desired output if I initialize the mongoURI variable with the URI. Here is the output.

mongodb://testuser:password@shard1:27017,shard1:27017,shard1:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0

However I need to read the mongoURI value from JSON input. When I do that, the first regex_replace does not recognize the variable(readinput).

```
- name: Fetch Mongo URI
      set_fact:
        mongoURI: "{{ (cluster_status_check.content | from_json).mongoURIWithOptions }}"
      when: cluster_status_check.status == 200
```

In this scenario, the last two regex_replaces are working fine but the first one is being replaced with the variable name as below.

*{{ readinput }}*shard1:27017,shard1:27017,shard1:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0

I tried to use urlsplit('hostname') but 'mongodb://' is not being recognized as hostname.

I also tried removing single quotes around readinput variable 
readconnstring: "{{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', {{ readinput }})) and removing {{ }} for the variable
readconnstring: "{{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', readinput))

but both are giving syntax errors.

Since from_json converts the output to a dict, I tried using with_items but no luck.

```
- name: Create Mongo connection string    
      set_fact:        
        readinput: "mongodb://{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).username }}:{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).password }}@" 
        readconnstring: "{{ item | regex_replace('mongodb://', '{{ readinput }}') | regex_replace('\\?ssl', 'test?ssl') + ('&retryWrites=true') }}"
  with_items:
        - "{{ mongoURI }}"
```

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    mongoURI: ""

- name: Check whether cluster already exists
      uri:
        url: https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/{{ groupid }}/clusters/{{ clustername }}
        return_content: yes
        method: GET
        user: "{{ user }}"
        password: "{{ apikey }}"
        status_code: 404, 200
      register: cluster_status_check
- name: Fetch Mongo URI
      set_fact:
        mongoURI: "{{ (cluster_status_check.content | from_json).mongoURIWithOptions }}"
      when: cluster_status_check.status == 200

- name: Create Mongo connection string    
      set_fact:        
        readinput: "mongodb://{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).username }}:{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).password }}@" 
        readconnstring: "{{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', '{{ readinput }}') | regex_replace('\\?ssl', 'test?ssl') + ('&retryWrites=true') }}"
```

Instead of replacing mongodb:// with the readinput value, it is being replaced as {{ readinput }}

Desired output:

mongodb://testuser:password@shard1:27017,shard1:27017,shard1:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0

Actual output:

{{ readinput }}shard1:27017,shard1:27017,shard1:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0

Comment: what is the syntax error that you get when you use readinput without `{{}}`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112403/in-ansible-how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-variable-definition-that-uses-filters) answer

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => { "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', readinput) }}): object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" }

Comment: could you try print the value of mongoURI before doing the regex_replace?

Comment: Yes, I am printing the same. `- name: Fetch Mongo URI
      set_fact:
        mongoURI: "{{ (cluster_status_check.content | from_json).mongoURIWithOptions }}"
      when: cluster_status_check.status == 200
    - debug:
        msg: "Fetched URI:{{ mongoURI }}"`                                                                   Here is the value. Changed a bit for privacy reasons. `mongodb://testcluster-shard-00-00-azure.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-01-azure.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-02-azure.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0`

Comment: I also printed right before the regex_replace and the mongoURI variable has the same content as given above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and fixed. The problem is with setting a variable and immediately using the same in the task.

```
- name: initialize variables
      set_fact:                
        readinput: "mongodb://{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).username }}:{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).password }}@"

- name: Create Mongo connection string    
      set_fact:        
        readconnstring: "{{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', readinput) | regex_replace('\\?ssl', 'test?ssl') + ('&retryWrites=true') }}"
```

As per the documentation, the variables set with set_fact are available to subsequent plays. When I moved the readinput initialization to a different task, then the code worked. I also don't have to wrap the variable inside {{ }}.

I wasted lot of time. Not sure why there is such limitation to set_fact.

Comment: amazing had this problem also  totally no logic in ansible DSL totally .....
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `'{{ readinput }}'`, `readinput` is enough.

Something like that should work:

```
- name: Create Mongo connection string    
  set_fact:        
    readinput: "mongodb://{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).username }}:{{ (userinfo_json.Users | first).password }}@" 
    readconnstring: "{{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', readinput) | regex_replace('\\?ssl', 'test?ssl') }}&retryWrites=true"
```

Comment: I already tried that. Here is the error I got.                                                              `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ mongoURI | regex_replace('mongodb://', readinput) }}): object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"
}`

Comment: It's probably a problem with `mongoURI`, fix that first

Comment: Here is the value of mongoURI when it was read from the JSON file. I have to change it a bit for privacy reasons.                                   
`mongodb://testcluster-shard-00-00-azure.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-01-azure.mongodb.net:27017,testcluster-shard-00-02-azure.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=TestCluster-shard-0`